# How do I wrap each set of two items with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, jquery-1.3

I'd like to wrap each set of the `<h2>` and `<table>` within their own `<div>` so I can manipulate the new container with CSS.

Below is a simplified version of the HTML I am working with:

```
<div>
<h3></h3>
<h2 class="product-line-term-name">Product 1</h2>
<table class="views-view-grid"></table>
<h3></h3>
<h2 class="product-line-term-name">Product 2</h2>
<table class="views-view-grid"></table>
<h3></h3>
<h2 class="product-line-term-name">Product 3</h2>
<table class="views-view-grid"></table>
</div>
```

Note: I am only working on the theme layer so jQuery (version 1.3.2) and CSS are my tools.

Comment: why cant you just manipulate the tags as is with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code

```
jQuery.each($('.product-line-term-name'), function(i, val) {
   //Create new element 
    var div = "<div>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + $(this).next()[0].outerHTML + "</div>";  

    $(this).prev().after(div);
    $(this).next().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prPY7/)

Comment: This worked for me on the version of jQuery (1.3.2) currently installed on the site.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) in this case:

```
$('h3').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div class="example" />');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9w9Sp/

Comment: That would work great but I just realized the site is running jQuery 1.3.2 and .nextUntil was added in 1.4

Comment: Then I'd suggest you upgrade your version since 1.3.2 is quite old and probably lack of many helpful features

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will serve your purpose for jQuery 1.3.2:

```
var h3_length = $('h3').length;

for(var i= h3_length - 1; i>= 0; i--) {
    $('h3').eq(i).nextAll().not(".test, h3").wrapAll('<div class="test" />');
}
```